# Is there a cleaner way to turn several delimited strings into a table in MySQL than this?

Tags: mysql, string

Often there is a situation where, e.g. web form input results in several arrays of the same length where each array is a different variable that needs to be included in a particular part of a query. Let's say you have...

`set @transforms = "a,b,c"; set @bys = "colX,colY,colZ";`

...and you want...

```
+------+---+------+
| row  | x | x    |
+------+---+------+
|    1 | a | colX |
|    2 | b | colY |
|    3 | c | colZ |
+------+---+------+
```

Is there a best practice for doing this, or at least a name for this type of problem? For all I know it might already be one of the examples on ArtfulSoftware, I just don't know what title to look for. The best I could come up with is the code below, but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel and I'd rather do it in whatever way is preferred by people who actually know what they're doing. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
DELIMITER ##
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS twoarrays ##
CREATE PROCEDURE hs.twoarrays
-- example usage: 
-- call twoarrays('array1','array2','delim1','delim2')
(
        IN array1   VARCHAR(2000),
        IN array2   VARCHAR(2000),
        IN delim1   VARCHAR(10),
        IN delim2   VARCHAR(10)
)
BEGIN
    IF delim1 is NULL THEN SET delim1 = ','; END IF;
    IF delim2 is NULL THEN SET delim2 = delim1; END IF;
    set @@group_concat_max_len = 99999;
    select @foo := concat("select @rowa := @rowa + 1 as row, '",
        replace(array1,delim1,"' x union select @rowa := @rowa + 1,'"),
        "' from (select @rowa := 0) r");
    select @bar := concat("select @rowb := @rowb + 1 as row, '",
        replace(array2,delim2,"' x union select @rowb := @rowb + 1,'"),
        "' from (select @rowb := 0) r");
    select @baz := concat("select a.*,b.x from (",
        @foo,
        ") a join (",
        @bar,
        ") b on a.row = b.row");
prepare twoarrayproc from @baz;
execute twoarrayproc;
END ## 
DELIMITER ; 

call twoarrays(@transforms,@bys,NULL,NULL);
```